# How do I get a value from a spreadsheet to show up on my web app?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to display a  value from my Google Sheets spreadsheet on a web app. I have a Code.gs function that retrieves a value from my spreadsheet. I then try to run that function in my html using google.script.run. I have read the documentation and watched numerous videos, but I can't seem to find a way to make it work.

```js
function doGet() {
  
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("stuff");
}
//this function deploys my web app

function getVal(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NpKADefhm1cVziviVfwAAcmv5PoMspFiFePo_CF1lW4/edit#gid=0");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Values").getRange("A1");
  var value = ws.getValue();
  //Logger.log(value);

return value
}
//this function retrieves a value from my spreadsheet
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function onSuccess(value){
       var div = document.getElementById('output');
       div.innerHtml = value;
    }
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getVal();
    //this function runs my apps script on the html side
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Stuff from Spreadsheet</h1> 
    <div id = "output"> </div>
    
   
  </body>
</html>
```

The only thing that shows up is the header from my html. How do I change my code to pull the value from my spreadsheet and display it on my web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please modify as follows and test it again. But in this case, it supposes that `value` is returned from `getVal()`.

#### From:

```
div.innerHtml = value;
```

#### To:

```
div.innerHTML = value;
```

#### Note:

- If you want to confirm whether `value` is returned from `getVal()`, please put `console.log(value)` after the line of `function onSuccess(value){`. By this, you can see it at the console.

#### Reference:

- [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Wow! It actually worked! Thank you! I guess I just needed to capitalize HTML, like you suggested. I think I get confused because there are methods containing "html" in which all but the first letter are lower case.